# how to increase height of row according to textview multiline enter word in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to know how to give textview at run time on tableviewcell .If i enter multiline text then textview height should be increase and at a same time row also should increase i have only one row and this row i have to put on textview with multiline and growing text with cell height help me in this

Comment: Please use punctuation. Your question is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

       UITextView *yourtextview;// use your memoir class textview. I am declare here temporary.
       CGSize s = [yourtextview.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] // enter your text font size and  cell-width
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourcellwidth, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    



       return s.height;    //this will give you height of text view you can change using addition according your requirements
}
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: @nit how to bring keyboard when i follow this code i not get textview on my table view cell when i click on 1row nothing is happen key board is not showing

Comment: you need to use textview in table. you just have to past your textview text in `CGSize s` for calculating textview height. Even you can use this code in function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correct: You want a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell, both with dynamic height, corresponding to the text in the TextView.

[Sensible TableView](http://www.sensiblecocoa.com/) has this function included (also some more).

[This Blog post](http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms) may also help.

[Question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4242916/470964)

I hope this links will help you. I think ou can work with the source code from the links to implement that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate size from your text which is in text view and then you can resize particular row or texview , 
method is -

`CGSize Size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWorldWrap];`