# How to Handle CellForRowAtIndexpath method

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I had one table view in which I had **15 row** in one section.
so when the table view get loaded it shows only **first 9 rows**, I checked it with method CellForRowAtIndexpath method but I want to get all 15 rows to be get called in this method for the viewload method.
please help me on out.

thanks in advance....

Comment: can you post your table method here.

Comment: The problem is that your tableView is too small to display all of them at once.  Either make your tableView larger, or make the cells smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends how much rows you set from

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

if you have an array then return 
`[arr count];` as number of rows and if you want static rows then use `return 15;` in this method

Comment: Or he means that the reuse ability of the table doesnt load initial offscreen items.

Comment: i thnk a question must have it's code included in question so that one can easily understand and answer it

Comment: @The Saad: I tried for [arr count] in numberOfRowsInSection but still it show me 9 rows on viewload but when i scroll the table view then all rows get displayed. I want to call all this 15 row in CellForRowAtIndexpath method to add each row cell.textView in other array.

Comment: @Wesso you are right! I want the reuse ability of the table doesnt load initial offscreen items. please help me

Comment: @SanjayDarshil post your code and mention in that what you want

Comment: Following is the code which i implemented                                                        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arrFields count];   }                                                                and // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   // In this method I get only first 9 cell.textview to add in array for each item in arrFields.}

Comment: are you sure you have 15 array fields? and post your cellForRow.. as it is here

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithString:strColname];
     
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
 {
  cell =[[[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier:0]autorelease]; 
    
    }

cell.label.text = [arrFields objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

// In this array i want to add this cell.textview
[ArrayCellText addObject:cell.textView]; 
}

Comment: Why would you want to preload every cell. You should never use a cell as your personal database.

Comment: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/ see this tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238760/how-to-make-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-uitextview-inside-that-dynamically-adjust see this thread

Answer (score 1):

You use these method or if you want all your cell on front of first time view then you should decrease the height of the cell using last method.And also check your array how much values he have.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return [Array count];

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];
 }
   cell.textLabel.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 20;//use this method for cell height
}
```