# Swift: How to continuously adapt a UICollectionViewCell height to a UITextView while writing in it?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

Good afternoon.

I've struggled with this "feature" for my iOS app for some hours now and I'm in need of some help.

**Question:** How should I implement so that when a user types in the `UITextView` increases in size (only the bottom margin) and the cell increases its height to fit the `UITextView` dynamically meanwhile? I can't figure out how to tackle it.

**Research:**
After some searching I came upon [Dynamically change cell's height while typing text, and reload the containing tableview for resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851614/dynamically-change-cells-height-while-typing-text-and-reload-the-containing-ta) as well as  [Can you animate a height change on a UITableViewCell when selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected/2063776#2063776)  I've also read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview but I feel my swift knowledge so far is inferior to whats expected in these posts.

In other words I cant figure out how to implement it for my UICollectionView.

My code at moment looks like this (I have more UI elements in the EventsCell but cut them out to save space, thus its only the bottom margin of the `UITextView` I want to change). I have set the RootCell as `delegate` for my `UITextView` and then i intend to grab the textView height as it is edited in order to get the height I want, but it isn't working.

**Cell class:**

```
class EventsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    setupViews()


  }
  let textView: GrowingTextView = { // GrowingTextView is a cocoapod extending UITextView
    let rootCellDelegate = RootCell()
    let tv = GrowingTextView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .clear
    tv.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    tv.isScrollEnabled = false
    tv.font = UIFont(name: "Didot", size: 16)
    tv.textColor = .black
    tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 6)
    tv.placeholder = "Write your event text here"
    tv.placeholderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tv.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
    tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    tv.delegate = rootCellDelegate
    return tv
}()

let eventPlaceholderMarkImage: UIButton = {
    let iv = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "placeHolderEventTitleMark")
    iv.setImage(image, for: .normal)

    return iv
}()

func setupViews() {


    //MARK: - Constraints for EventsCell
    //horizontal
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0(\(frame.width - 32))]-16-|", views: textView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-47-[v0]-16-|", views: textView)

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: eventPlaceholderMarkImage, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: -7))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: eventPlaceholderMarkImage, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-12-[v0(27)]-\(cellWidth - 39)-|", views: eventPlaceholderMarkImage)
}
}
```

**UICollectionView class:**

```
class RootCell: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

      var textViewHeight : CGFloat?

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textViewHeight = textView.textContainer.size.height + 63
    collectionView.reloadInputViews()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.layoutSubviews()


}

  lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
      let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
      let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
      cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
      cv.delegate = self
      cv.dataSource = self
      return cv
  }()

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

    collectionView.register(EventsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: EventCellID)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: EventCellID, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let height = textViewHeight ?? frame.width * 1/3
    let width = frame.width - 8
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

//MARK: - Design selected cells background

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? EventsCell {

        cell.textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.eventTitleLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.flatBlack.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        cell.backgroundColor = GradientColor(.topToBottom, frame: cell.frame, colors: [UIColor.flatRed.withAlphaComponent(0.2), UIColor.white])


    } else {return}

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    } else {return}

}
}
```

**Attempt after first answer:**

```
class RootCell: BaseCell, UITextViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var textViewText : String?

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    textViewText = textView.text
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadInputViews()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }


}

func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {

    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    guard let boundingBox = textViewText?.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil) else {return frame.width * 1/3}

    return boundingBox.height
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = frame.width - 8
    let height = heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font: UIFont(name: "Didot", size: 16)!)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

}
```

Thank you for reading my post!

Comment: Might also want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout

Comment: @deniz's answer seems works good, I think u'd better to accept it if u've solved by the solution provided. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Reloading the collection view or the individual cell will flicker the cells and the user would lose focus on the TextView as they type. If the user loses focus, they have to click on the UITextView again to keep on typing.

When you detect that your UITextView needs resizing, you can invalidate your collectionview's layout - which will cause your cells to be resized if your auto-layout parameters are all correct. See example below:

1. I have a UICollectionCell with only UITextView inside of it, and scrolling on the UITextView is **disabled**. UITextView is properly constrained to all edges of the cell using AutoLayout. Finally, the cell is also the UITextView's delegate as such:

   ```
   class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet private weak var myTextView: UITextView!

     //this local variable will be used to determine if the intrinsic content size has changed or not
     private var textViewHeight: CGFloat = .zero
     ...
     ...
     override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      myTextView.delegate = self
     }
     ...
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Conform this cell to UITextViewDelegate

   ```
   extension MyCollectionCell: UITextViewDelegate { 

   func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
     //this assumes that collection view already correctly laid out the cell
     //to the correct height for the contents of the UITextView
     //textViewHeight simply needs to catch up to it before user starts typing
     let fittingSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: myTextView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
     textViewHeight = fittingSize.height

     return true
   }

   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     //flag to determine whether textview's size is changing
     var shouldResize = false
     //calculate fitting size after the content has changed
     let fittingSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: myTextView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

     //if the current height is not equal to the fitting height
     //save the new fitting height to our local variable and inform the delegate 
     //that collection view needs resizing
     if textViewHeight != fittingSize.height {
       shouldResize = true
       //save the new height 
       textViewHeight = fittingSize.height
     }

     //notify the cell's delegate (most likely a UIViewController) 
     //that UITextView's intrinsic content size has changed
     //perhaps with a protocol such as this:
     delegate?.textViewDidChange(newText: textView.text, alsoRequiresResize: shouldResize)
   }
   ```
3. Then when the delegate receives the notification, perhaps saves the updated text and updates the layout such as this:

   ```
   myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
   ```

The best part of this solution is that you do not have to invoke collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:).

Cheers!

Comment: Hello! 
Thank you for provided solution! 
I've decided to use compositional layouts for my collectionViews so I'm trying to implement your solution but with no success so far. CollectionView cells are not resizing after invalidateLayout() are invoked. 
Could you please provide code with how you handled item/group/section layout? I think my problem probably lies in how I've setup my section provider code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Wilhelm, if you define the section/cell layout as follows  `NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(60))`, it should work. In this code the cell takes up the entire available width and has an estimated height of 60 pts. I also wrote a [blog post](https://deniznessa.medium.com/create-forms-with-compositional-layout-in-uicollectionview-d89e6b6923c2) about this if you want to see the full implementation.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for me, with iOS16 (maybe even before) you can replace the final delegate call with calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() on the cell if a resize is needed.

Answer (score 0):

First store `textView` text in some variable then you can get height of your text by this method

```
func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)
    return boundingBox.height
}
```

then pass this in height for cell + your paddings
and don't forget to reload your `collectionView` when user enters something

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have some problem implementing it. I've edited my question with my try of it and would be grateful if you could take a quick look?

Comment: did you constrained you textView from bottom? and can you explain what problem you are facing now?

Comment: I told you to save your textView text in some variable and add this method to String Extension and get height of your text.

Comment: Add this method into String Extension and then "Your variable.thisMethod" and pass width and font will return height of your text and then that height + your textView padding from top and bottom.